# Using .write() to append a file, but want to use a variable

Tags: python, file, datetime, append, syntax-error

In my code I have a file opened, and I want to append to the file the current date and time. I'm using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) to get the date

```
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now()
```

And assigning the current date/time to a variable called "currenttime"

```
print(currenttime)
with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
    log.write(currenttime)
```

When I try to do this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is becuase you're trying to write a datetime object to a text file. You can convert the datetime object in a few different ways to make it writable, for example:

```
str(currenttime)
```

or

```
currenttime.isoformat()
```

ie:

```
with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(str(currenttime))
```

If you want to use a special format of your timestamp you can use `strftime`, for example:

```
In [1]: datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[1]: '2016-03-01 23:52:36'
```

You can read more about formatting the datetime here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

From the name of your file and the fact you're adding a timestamp it might be a good idea to look into the logging module in python, if logging is what you want. It's very well suited for that purpose instead of manually writing to a file: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 2):

Convert `currenttime` to string with [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

```
with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(str(currenttime))
```

Note that you should write to your file with `f.write()`, not `log.write()`.

Answer (score 1):

Typecast `datetime` object to `str`

```
log.write(str(currenttime))
```